# ERROR when using malloc() and sizeof() function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc, stack

Following is a program I made in C for implementation of stack using array and pointers:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct ArrayStack {
  int top;
  int capacity;
  int *array;
};
struct ArrayStack *createStack(int cap) {
  struct ArrayStack *stack;
  stack = malloc(sizeof(struct Arraystack));
  stack->capacity = cap;
  stack->top = -1;
  stack->array(malloc(sizeof(int) * stack->capacity));
  return stack;
}
int isFull(struct ArrayStack *stack) {
  if(stack->top == stack->capacity-1)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}
int isEmpty(struct ArrayStack *stack) {
  if(stack->top == -1)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}
void push(struct ArrayStack *stack, int item) {
  if(!isFull(stack)) {
    stack->top++;
    stack->array[stack->top] = item;
  } else {
    printf("No more memory available!");
  }
}
void pop(struct ArrayStack *stack) {
  int item;
  if(!isEmpty(stack)) {
    item = stack->array[stack->top];
    stack->top--;
  } else {
    printf("Memory is already empty!");
  }
}
int main() {
  struct ArrayStack *stack;
  stack = createStack(10);
  int choise;
  int item;
  while(1) {
    system("clear");
    printf("\n1. Push");
    printf("\n2. Pop");
    printf("\n3. Exit");
    printf("\n\n\n\t\tPlease choose your option!");
    scanf("%d",&choise);
    switch(choise) {
    case 1:
      printf("\nEnter a number");
      scanf("%d",&item);
      push(stack,item);
      break;
    case 2:
      pop(stack);
      break;
    case 3:
      exit(0);
      break;
    default :
      printf("\nPlease enter a valid choise!");
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

The following error is coming whenever I try to compile this code using gcc compiler:

```
prog.c:10:25: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct Arraystack'
   stack = malloc(sizeof(struct Arraystack));
                         ^
prog.c:13:3: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
   stack->array(malloc(sizeof(int) * stack->capacity));
   ^
```

I have used online IDEs like ideone and codechef's ide but same error is coming again. I am totally struck, this is really annoying!

Comment: `sizeof(struct ArrayStack)` the capital `S` Voted to close as a typo

Answer (score 2):

First your errors:

```
stack = malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayStack));
```

You typed `Arraystack` (lower case `s`).

```
stack->array=malloc(sizeof(int) * stack->capacity);
```

You typed `stack->array(malloc(sizeof(int) * stack->capacity));` which is syntactically a function call which is why the compiler complains about `array` not being a function pointer.

In addition:

1. Introduce a function `void destroyStack(ArrayStack* stack)` to `free()` the `malloc()`ed space in `createStack()`. Call it towards the end of `main()` when you've finished with the stack.

Always render unto `free()` what `malloc()` rendered unto thee.

2. Your `pop()` doesn't return the popped value.
3. You should probably return values indicating failure when `push()` and `pop()` fail.